# Find and Replace CSV File w/Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a script that creates random passwords and stores them in a csv file with different informational headers such as `$username, $system, $password`.  This script is run in a new environment to create randomly generated passwords for service accounts.  Every 90 days the people managing this environment will need to change these passwords so I am trying to create a script that will then change the passwords and update the csv file with the new ones.  I am able to change the passwords without a problem, but modifying the csv file has been another story all together.

My Function, `Function UpdatePassword ($username,$system,$password)` will receive the following line:

```
$result = UpdatePassword $entry.Name "Active Directory" "${account_password}"
```

I want to search the csv file and match the username I am editing with the corresponding username in the CSV file.  However, because some usersnames may be the same (just accept this) I also need to check against the $system variable, which in this case is "Active Directory".  If both of these values match a line, then I want to replace the $password with the new one.

```
function UpdatePassword($username,$system,$password) { if($(hostname)
-eq "Machine") {   New-PSDrive -Name AdminShare -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $LOCALPASSWORDFILE | Out-Null } else {   New-PSDrive -Name AdminShare -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $REMOTEPASSWORDFILE | Out-Null } $PASSWORDFILE = "AdminShare:\Passwords.csv"

##########
#Checking for required values
##########

if(!$username -or !$system) {   write-host "username, system, and special characters fields are required"   return "invalid arguments" }

$pwFile = import-csv $PASSWORDFILE

foreach ($user in $pwFile) {   
    if($user.username.tolower() -eq $username.tolower() -and $system.tolower() -eq $userem.tolower())   {       
        $_ -replace $user.Password, $password | Set-Content $pwFile;
    }
return 0   
 }

  Remove-PSDrive -Name AdminShare | out-null }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Import-Csv` you read a CSV file into an array of PowerShell custom objects where each field of the CSV is represented by a property on the each custom object.  You don't want to treat that as a string and attempt to write the string back to the CSV file. Instead, modify the properties on the objects e.g. inside you `if` do this:

```
$user.Password = $password
```

Then outside your foreach loop, export the objects back out to a CSV file e.g.:

```
$pwFile | Export-File $PASSWORDFILE -NoTypeInformation
```